# D8 - How to modify url params on form submit?

Tags: forms

Im using form_alter on a views exposed filter form. There are 2 date fields (start-date and end-date) which are exposed filters that Ive hidden from the user. I want to populate the url argument of these 2 fields when the form is submitted.

Ive tried both methods using a submit and validation callback but neither seems to work.

My form_alter is:

```
function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, 
  FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-my-form-id') {
  ...
  ...

  $form['#submit'][] = '_my_custom_submit';
  $form['#validate'][] = '_my_custom_validate';
}
```

My callback looks like:

```
function _my_custom_validate($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  // Pass date range selection to date fields.
  $date_range = $form_state->getValue('date-range');
  $date_range_split = explode(":", $date_range, 2);
  $start_date = $date_range_split[0];
  $end_date = $date_range_split[1];

  $form_state->setValue('start-date', $start_date);
  $form_state->setValue('end-date', $end_date);

  $input = &$form_state->getUserInput();
  $input['start-date'] = $start_date;
  $input['end-date'] = $start_date;
  $form_state->setUserInput($input);
}
```

When I dpm() any of my vars above I see the data but I can not get it passed into the url's arg on submit so I keep getting http://domain.com&start-date=&end-date=

How can I populate/modify the url args after the user clicks submit but before the page reloads?

If theres any other info that I can provide that may be helpful, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might have a logic-error in

```
$input['end-date'] = $start_date;
```

should be this:?

```
$input['end-date'] = $end_date;
```

How ever you can add a parameter with "query->add":

```
\Drupal::request()->query->add(['start-date' => $start_date, 'end-date' => $end_date]);
```

Note that you "mix" POST and GET - variable. So in your "submitForm" - method you need to process the GET - variables by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response @calar. Ah yes, you are right, that var should be $end-date. But \Drupal::request()->query->add() doesnt seem to be working. Ive been able to accomplish what i need by just updating the hidden fields with jquery. I was hoping there was a more drupal way to do this without js.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping there was a more drupal way to do this without js but ended up just using js to populate the fields before form is submit.